# Javascript highscore counter not updating

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make a game that measures your reaction time, but my fastest score tracker is very buggy. It works during the first reaction test but after that stops working. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

```
<!DOCTPYE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload = alert("Press START to start the game. As soon as the screen turns red click the stop button. Get the fastest time you can. Good luck");
var button = document.getElementById("reactionTester");
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var startTime;
var scoreContainer = document.getElementById("p");
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type= "text/css";
var counter = 0;
var timer = null;
var highscore = document.getElementById("highscore");
var currentRecord = 0;
var highscoreCounter = 0;
function init(){
var startInterval/*in milliseconds*/ = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)*1000;
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(startTimer,1/*startInterval*/);
document.body.appendChild(css);
css.innerHTML = "html{background-color: blue;}";
}
function startTimer(){

startTime = Date.now();
css.innerHTML="null";
css.innerHTML = "html{background-color: red;}";
if(counter==1){
p1 = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1];
p1.parentNode.removeChild(p1);
counter++;
}
}

function stopTimer(){
if(startTime){
var stopTime = Date.now();
var dif = stopTime - startTime;
alert("Your time is " + dif + " ms");
startTime = null;
css.innerHTML = null;
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(p);
p.innerHTML = dif;
counter=1;
if (highscoreCounter != 0){
    if(dif < currentRecord){
        Phighscore2 = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
        Phighscore2.parentNode.removeChild(Phighscore2);
        document.getElementById("highscore").appendChild(highscoreP);
        currentRecord = dif;
        highscoreP.innerHTML = currentRecord;
    }
    else{}
}
else{
    var highscoreP = document.createElement("p");
    document.getElementById("highscore").appendChild(highscoreP);
    currentRecord = dif;
    highscoreP.innerHTML = currentRecord;
    highscoreCounter++;
}
}
else{
alert("don't trick me");
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="highscore">

</div>
<form id="form">
<div class="tableRow">
<input type="button" value="start" id="start" onclick="init()">
</div>
<div class="tableRow">
<input type="button" id="reactionTester" onclick="stopTimer()" value="stop">
</div>
<div id="p">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this problem is too specific for Stack.

Comment: do you know anywebsites that it's not too specific for?

Comment: Nope. But the Stack community focuses on broader problems that may be of help to others (think a web search). The chances of somebody else stumbling upon the same problem as you is minuscule here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Well Your code is working fine at my side. I tested your code and it's working fine

Comment: But the highscore counter it's taking the latest score isn't it? Instead of the fastest score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that variable `highscoreP` is defined locally in `function stopTimer`. Local variables lose their value upon function return. Make it a global variable (and do not forget to remove its 'var' keyword inside the function).

I cannot resist making some additional remarks about your code:

- Do not create the same DOM elements over and over again; it complicates your code and stresses out the browser's memory manager. Define all elements statically and refer to them by ID as you already did with the containers (highscore, p).
- Do not build a *style* element dynamically, this is really bad practice. Instead, define CSS classes statically, then assign the classes dynamically by setting attribute className.
- Even though you are doing a pretty good job programming in plain javascript, you may want to consider using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks you soo much!! I was trying to solve this problem for a long time. And thanks for the jquery advice, and if you don't mind me asking, do you know what parts of my code would be made shorter with jquery?

Comment: DOM-wise, your code is not complex, so jQuery will not greatly reduce the number of lines. But in general, it does help improve maintainability and browser support. With some serious refactoring you should be able to eliminate some lines of code, and some variables too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I checked jquery out and it's very convenient